# Javascript un-able to get data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

On my codeigniter project I have created a model were when user can delete a page but before he or she does it pops up with a warning bootstrap modal.

For some reason I can not get my `data-id` to get picked up by my script.
So what happens when I click on yes to delete it sends me to `http://localhost/codeigniter/cms-1/admin/catalog/information/delete/` but should pick up data-id and ad it after delete example `http://localhost/codeigniter/cms-1/admin/catalog/information/delete/2`

Question: Why does the script not detect and grab my data-id and add it to url when click yes on modal?

I think this part here not working correct

> `removeBtn.attr('href', removeBtn.attr('href').replace(/(&|\?)\d*/, '$1' + id));`

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#modal-from-dom').on('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');

    removeBtn.attr('href', removeBtn.attr('href').replace(/(&|\?)\d*/, '$1' + id));

    $('#debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + removeBtn.attr('href') + '</strong>');
});

$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#modal-from-dom').data('id', id).modal('show');
}); 
</script>
```

View where data-id is `data-id="<?php echo $information['information_id'];?>"`

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="pull-left">
<h1 class="panel-title" style="padding-top: 7.5px;"><?php echo $heading_title;?></h1>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/catalog/information/add');?>" role="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Information Page</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Information Title</td>
<td class="text-right">Delete</td>
<td class="text-right">Action</td>
</tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if ($informations) {?>
<?php foreach ($informations as $information) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $information['title'];?></td>
    <td class="text-right">
    <a href="<?php echo $information['delete'];?>" class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete" data-id="<?php echo $information['information_id'];?>">Delete <?php echo $information['title'];?></a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
    <a href="<?php echo $information['edit'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit <?php echo $information['title'];?></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr>
<td class="text-center" colspan="4">No Results</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
</div>
</div><!-- .panel .panel-default -->
```

Modal

```
<?php if ($informations) {?>
<?php foreach ($informations as $information) {?>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-from-dom">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are about to delete one track url, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
        <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
        <p id="debug-url"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="admin/catalog/information/delete/" class="btn danger">Yes</a>
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn secondary">No</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<?php }?>
<?php }?>
```

Full View

```
<?php echo $header;?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="clearfix">
<div class="pull-left">
<h1 class="panel-title" style="padding-top: 7.5px;"><?php echo $heading_title;?></h1>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/catalog/information/add');?>" role="button" class="btn btn-success">Add Information Page</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Information Title</td>
<td class="text-right">Delete</td>
<td class="text-right">Action</td>
</tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php if ($informations) {?>
<?php foreach ($informations as $information) {?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $information['title'];?></td>
    <td class="text-right">
    <a href="<?php echo $information['delete'];?>" class="btn btn-danger confirm-delete" data-id="<?php echo $information['information_id'];?>">Delete <?php echo $information['title'];?></a>
    </td>
    <td class="text-right">
    <a href="<?php echo $information['edit'];?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit <?php echo $information['title'];?></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
<?php } else { ?>
<tr>
<td class="text-center" colspan="4">No Results</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
</div>
</div><!-- .panel .panel-default -->
</div>
</div>

<?php if ($informations) {?>
<?php foreach ($informations as $information) {?>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-from-dom">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are about to delete one track url, this procedure is irreversible.</p>
        <p>Do you want to proceed?</p>
        <p id="debug-url"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="admin/catalog/information/delete/" class="btn danger">Yes</a>
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn secondary">No</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
<?php }?>
<?php }?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#modal-from-dom').on('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');

    removeBtn.attr('href', removeBtn.attr('href').replace(/(&|\?)\d*/, '$1' + id));

    $('#debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + removeBtn.attr('href') + '</strong>');
});

$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#modal-from-dom').data('id', id).modal('show');
}); 
</script>

</div>

<?php echo $footer;?>
```

Comment: instead of PHP, provide the rendered HTML . and this works `<span data-id='some value' id='temp'></span><script>    alert($('#temp').data('id'))</script>` from jQuery 1.6.4 & above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#modal-from-dom').on('show', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'),
        removeBtn = $(this).find('.danger');

    removeBtn.attr('href', removeBtn.attr('href').replace(/(&|\?)\d*/, '$1' + id));

    $('#debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + removeBtn.attr('href') + '</strong>');
});

$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#modal-from-dom').data('id', id).modal('show');
}); 
</script>
```

Use `var id = $(this).attr('data-id');` only on the `.confirm-delete` element.